# Prompt user to select image from folder in MATLAB GUI to calculate PSNR and MSE

Tags: matlab, user-input, matlab-guide, mse

I have written this code:

```
InputImage=imread('ground truth 1.jpg');
ReconstructedImage=imread('final1.jpg');
n=size(InputImage);
 M=n(1);
 N=n(2);
 MSE = sum(sum((InputImage-ReconstructedImage).^2))/(M*N);
PSNR = 10*log10(256*256/MSE);
 fprintf('\nMSE: %7.2f ', MSE);
 fprintf('\nPSNR: %9.7f dB', PSNR);
```

How do I modify the coding to prompt the user to select an image for `InputImage` and `OutputImage` from a folder? I have tried something like this before

```
[InFile, InPath] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Import image file:');
if ~ischar(InFile)
  disp('User aborted file import');
  return;
end
[OutFile, OutPath] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Export image file:', InPath);
if ~ischar(OutFile)
  disp('User aborted file export');
  return;
end
InFile  = fullfile(InPath, InFile);
OutFile = fullfile(OutPath, OutFile);
```

but I got an error:

```
Matirx dimension not agree error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work just fine.

```
[InFile, InPath] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Import image file:');
if ~ischar(InFile)
  disp('User aborted file import');
  return;
end

[OutFile, OutPath] = uigetfile('*.jpg', 'Export image file:', InPath);
if ~ischar(OutFile)
  disp('User aborted file export');
  return;
end
InFile  = fullfile(InPath, InFile);
OutFile = fullfile(OutPath, OutFile);

InputImage=imread(InFile);
ReconstructedImage=imread(OutFile);
n=size(InputImage);
 M=n(1);
 N=n(2);
 MSE = sum(sum((InputImage-ReconstructedImage).^2))/(M*N);
PSNR = 10*log10(256*256/MSE);
 fprintf('\nMSE: %7.2f ', MSE);
 fprintf('\nPSNR: %9.7f dB', PSNR);
```

Make sure the size of `InputImage` and `ReconstructedImage` are same.

Comment: for your information, both files are available in the folder. When i run the coding without prompting user input, it works fine. But after I modify the coding to prompt for user input, it gives matrix dimension not agree error. Any solution to this?

Comment: That error is show at which line of the above posted code?

Comment: If the error is shown in `MSE = sum(sum((InputImage-ReconstructedImage).^2))/(M*N);` then it is because, matrix dimension of `InputImage` and `ReconstructedImage` are different. Look in the matlab workspace to confirm.

Comment: The code works fine now. And another thing, how do I display those PSNR and MSE values on 'edit text' in MATLAB GUI?

Comment: `set(handles.edit1, 'string', MSE);` where `edit1` is the tag name of edit text

Comment: what if I want to display PSNR on one edit text and MSE on another edit text? Do I use the same coding?

Comment: each edit text has a unique tag name. If the tag name of MSE is `edit1` and tag name of PSNR is `edit2`. Then  `set(handles.edit1, 'string', MSE);`  `set(handles.edit2, 'string', PSNR);`

Comment: In the matlab GUI editor click on the `edit text` and tag name will be shown at bottom left corner. Something like `Tag: edit1`

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Everything works just how I wanted it to be. thanks